# Не могу запустить keras-tuner LSTM сеть

Tags: keras

Использую новую библиотеку kerastuner, но возникла проблема с LSTM сетями.

```
def build_model(hp):
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(units=hp.Int('units',
                                        min_value=32,
                                        max_value=512,
                                        step=32),input_shape=(total_x_total.shape[1],total_x_total.shape[2]),batch_size = 1))
 model.add(Dense(attack_matrix_total.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
 return model


tuner = RandomSearch(build_model, objective='val_accuracy', max_trials=5,directory='test_directory')
```

Такая сеть вовращает ошибку ""RuntimeError: Model-building function did not return a valid Model instance".". Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: можете привести пример сети lstm, которая пройдет компиляцию.

Answer (score 1):

Может кто столкнется. Проблема была решена, я добавлял не from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, а из самого keras'a.